# Where can I ask about if an online service exists?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am looking for an online service to generate a chart over a custom keyboard layout for e.g. gaming, but I'm unsure - does a Stack Exchange site exist where such a question would be considered off-topic? My initial thought was [Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User), but reading the about page, it doesn't really seem to fit there either?

It's pretty "easy" question, but does it fit somewhere in Stack Exchange?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ could be one, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Why does it have to be an online service - would an application/app not work as well?

Comment: It would yes, I was just trying to limit the scope, and online services could easier implement nice to have features like recommended setups and sharing.

Comment: @taskinoor: Thanks, I missed that one somehow, and I actually think it might fit there. I'll have to give it a go. Thanks. :)

Comment: @taskinoor no, that's incorrect. It'll be closed on [webapps.se].

Comment: @Sathya thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @Sathya if the about page is to be believed I can't see how that is? Take this example from meta: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/double-standards-on-web-app-recommendation-questions/1003#1003 - I'll try updating my question here, and see if you agree that it can fit anyways (AFK for a few hours though).

Comment: @JohnySkovdal http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask such questions end up being list of x, which don't really fit well.

Comment: @Sathya but isn't that exactly what this line is for: `"App recommendations unless prior research is shown"` ?

Comment: @JohnySkovdal in theory - yes. In practice app research is something which no one ever does.

Answer (score 4):

There is no site in the Stack Exchange family where asking for recommendations for a service/library/book etc. to achieve a particular task is going to be considered on topic as there can not be a single objective answer. Some people might prefer one service, others might prefer another and some might find shortcomings with both of them (or as many more as there are).

This leads to a not constructive discussion, which goes against our model.

You would probably have better luck asking on a mailing list or forum where the model is more relaxed about objectivity.

Comment: Well after searching quite a bit, I've found no services that does it for me, so a working solution is really "good enough", and no reason for a subjective discussion. It's more along the lines: "Is there a tool/service that can accomplish X for me". But I see that subjectivity can easily crawl into it though.

Comment: @JohnySkovdal - I suggest reading [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). If you stick through to the end, it has a way to turn this kind of question to a constructive one...

Comment: @Oded: The one here in Meta, or the one I'd like to ask?

Comment: @JohnySkovdal - The one you would like to ask.